# AutoresizingMask - Fixed bottom position

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm having trouble getting AutoresizingMasks to work.

What I want is a view, that contains another view (UITextView) which is aligned to the bottom of the first view after resize.

I have a parent UIView that looks like this:

```
UIView *parentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,568)];
[parentView setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];
```

Then I have a child view that looks like this:

```
UITextView *childView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 400, 300, 10)];
[childView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
```

Now, I add text and resize the view:

```
[childView setText:@"A long text that's bigger than the view."];
[childView sizeToFit];
```

The childView, however, grows downwards instead of upwards.

How do I anchor the childView to the bottom? What am I missing? :)

I'm not using storyboards or any other xib/nib-files. Just pure code.

Comment: [childView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight]; does this help?

Comment: No, this doesn't help :(. As I understand it, BottomMargin should be used to anchor stuff to the top. And reverse for bottom (in theory).

Answer (score 0):

Autoresizing works only when the `parentView`'s size being changed.
And they don't remember the **old** `frame` of its subviews.

So, you have to manually adjust the `frame` of `childView` after `sizeToFit`:

```
CGRect oldFrame = childView.frame;
CGFloat bottomY = oldFrame.position.y + oldFrame.size.height;
[childView setText:@"A long text that's bigger than the view."];
[childView sizeToFit];
CGRect newFrame = childView.frame;
newFrame.position.y = bottomY - newFrame.size.height;
childView.frame = newFrame;
```